# Spring Integration Mail Adapter Using Wrong User

Tags: java, spring, grails, jakarta-mail

We have a Spring Integration process that is using an Email Adpater to programatically read email from a GMail account. When it runs on my local PC, everything runs fine. When we deploy this to our Linux server (Linux 2.6.32-279.11.1.el6.x86_64), then the same configuration looks like it is using the server account that the application runs under and not the parameter that is configured in Spring.

We are trying to connect to **mail.account@gmail.com**

```
<mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter id="customAdapter"
      store-uri="imaps://mail.account:password@imap.gmail.com/INBOX"
      java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties"
      channel="receiveEmailChannel"
      should-delete-messages="false"
      should-mark-messages-as-read="true"
      auto-startup="true">
</mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter>
```

Running on my PC, I get the following from the mail.debug logging. Notice that the user is **mail.account**

```
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 XYZZY SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH AUTH=XOAUTH2 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN
A0 OK Thats all she wrote! y4if3012170qcp.27
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: XOAUTH
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: XOAUTH2
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN
DEBUG: protocolConnect login, host=imap.gmail.com, user=mail.account, password=<non-null>
A1 AUTHENTICATE PLAIN
```

Running on Linux, I get the following from the mail.debug logging. Notice that the user is **server.account**

```
DEBUG: trying to connect to host "imap.gmail.com", port 993, isSSL true
* OK Gimap ready for requests from 999.999.9.999 u6if3552599icy.8
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 XYZZY SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH AUTH=XOAUTH2 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN
A0 OK Thats all she wrote! u6if3552599icy.8
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: XOAUTH
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: XOAUTH2
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN
DEBUG: protocolConnect login, host=imap.gmail.com, user=server.account, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command result: A1 NO Invalid credentials u6if3552599icy.8
```

This is a Grails app and we have a build management system in place to do the builds and deploys, so I'm fairly confident that the jar files and configuration should be the same.

I'm at the end of my rope trying to track this down. Anyone ever experience this before?

Comment: It seems javamail uses system properties for configuration. Are you sure your java system properties are not being overwritten somewhere in your production server? Print debug logging statements to check the system property values maybe?

Comment: @gerrytan I thought of that as well, but the only place that the `imap.gmail.com` is specified is in the Email Adapter configuration in Spring Integration. I originally had the email connection string paramaterized, but I hard-coded it with the actual email address.  If it is using system properties, then it is taking the domain from the `store-uri` parameter and only replacing the user account. I'd have to add the debugging to the Grails code. The SI configuration is fairly simple, but I don't know how it handles the system properties. This is a tough one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wound up being an issue with the Grails packaging and distribution of the war. There is still more work and investigation needed for our final solution, but I think that may wind up being a separate StackOverflow question.

The basic issue was that when Grails creates the WAR, it includes jar files for several servlet containers, including Geronimo. The Geronimo jars were not present, but were in the WAR package. For the deployed version of the WAR, we stopped the app, went to `WEB-INF/lib` and removed `geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.7.1.jar`, and restarted the app. Everything works great now. The authentication in Geronimo must be different/broken.

Now we just need to find out how to exclude the Geronimo jars from our distribution.

---

The final culprit was the `ws-client` plugin that was included in `application.properties`. Once this was removed, we no longer had any `geronimo-*.jar` files included in the prroject.

```
plugins.ws-client=1.0
```

---